# Ошибка после остановки py файла

Tags: python, opencv, pyautogui

У меня есть код и он корректно работает:

```
import time
import pyautogui as pga
import pydirectinput as pda

fish_path = 'imgs/fish.png'
time.sleep(3)
while True:
    pda.press('e')
    fish = pga.locateOnScreen(fish_path, confidence=0.8)
    if fish != None:
        i = 0
        while i<10:
            x = fish[0]
            y = fish[1]
            x = int(x)
            y = int(y)
            if pga.pixelMatchesColor(x + 6, y + 6, (15, 156, 236), tolerance=10) == False:
                print('break fish')
                break
            if i == 10:
                print('break i ')
                break
            if pga.pixelMatchesColor(x + 100, y + 50, (212, 213, 215), tolerance=30) == True:
                pda.press('up')
                i = i + 1
            elif pga.pixelMatchesColor(x + 200, y + 130, (212, 213, 215), tolerance=30) == True:
                pda.press('right')
                i = i + 1
            elif pga.pixelMatchesColor(x + 100, y + 130, (212, 213, 215), tolerance=30) == True:
                pda.press('down')
                i = i + 1
            elif pga.pixelMatchesColor(x + 30, y + 130, (212, 213, 215), tolerance=30):
                pda.press('left')
                i = i + 1
```

Но после остановки в консоли появляется ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\game\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    pda.press('e')
  File "D:\Python\game\venv\lib\site-packages\pydirectinput\__init__.py", line 242, in wrapper
    returnVal = wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\game\venv\lib\site-packages\pydirectinput\__init__.py", line 545, in press
    upped = keyUp(k)
  File "D:\Python\game\venv\lib\site-packages\pydirectinput\__init__.py", line 243, in wrapper
    _handlePause(funcArgs.get("_pause"))
  File "D:\Python\game\venv\lib\site-packages\pydirectinput\__init__.py", line 232, in _handlePause
    time.sleep(PAUSE)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

А если удалить строку `pda.press('e')` то появляется другая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\game\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    fish = pga.locateOnScreen(fish_path, confidence=0.8)
  File "D:\Python\game\venv\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 175, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\game\venv\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 213, in locateOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\game\venv\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 373, in locateOnScreen
    retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\game\venv\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 353, in locate
    points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
  File "D:\Python\game\venv\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 229, in _locateAll_opencv
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(haystackImage, needleImage, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Как исправить эту ошибку ?

Comment: А как вы его останавливаете?

Comment: @Александр красной кнопкой в пайчарм, или ctrl+c в консоли

Answer (score 0):

Так как вариант:

```
import time
import pyautogui as pag


def programm():
    i = 0
    while True:
        print(i)
        i += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        
def main():
    try:
        programm()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Программа остановлена пользователем...")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```